# MVC Model Binding with Attribute Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

Converting an MVC 3 app to MVC 5 and relying exclusively on Attribute Routing. All is good but I am unable to define a route for a controller method that accepts a (not so) complex object as a parameter.

If I omit the parameter in the route, my controller/method is never invoked and I receive a 404 (as I would expect). When I include the `viewModel` parameter as part of the route, my method is invoked but the parameter is always `null`.

This code worked fined before with "classic" routing and no specific route was needed to model bind my `viewModel` parameter. I never defined it as part of any route other than including the controller and method names. The view is unchanged.

```
[RoutePrefix("Text")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class TextController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{jobTextID}")]
    public ViewResult Edit(Guid jobTextID)
    {
        // this (get) works fine
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{viewModel}"]
    public RedirectToRouteResult Edit(TextEditViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // viewModel is always null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should add the id to the POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{jobTextID}")]
public RedirectToRouteResult Edit(Guid jobTextID, TextEditViewModel viewModel) { }
```

The resource is identified by the URL, not by a parameter in the body of the request. Use `jobTextID` to retrieve the entity from the database and ignore the id from the viewModel.

Comment: Great point about routing to the URL and not the controller methods / parameters. I wasn't thinking along those lines. Fixed. Thanks much.

Comment: PS: You can drop `jobTextID` as a parameter. It only needs to be included in the route. `[Route("{jobTextID}")]Edit(TextEditViewModel viewModel)` works fine.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the point of viewModel being there, if we cannot get any value from it.

Comment: From my experiment, it seems that ModelBinder/automatic binding doesn't work for attribute routing, but it will work for conventional routing. I'm not sure if we can customize the app to support Model Binder with Attribute Routing though.